# Is there a limitation for Faye subscribers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faye

[Faye](https://faye.jcoglan.com/) service is used for publish-subscribe messaging system.
I am using it for Ruby.

I can't find the information what is the limitation on the number of subscribers to a channel?

For example, if I have a 1000 subscribers to a channel `/notification`, when the number of subscribers will be too much?